# How do you insert the command contents in VIM

Tags: vim

I'm a new user to vim. I would like to save a macro to my .vimrc file that inserts a date stamp into my document. For example this:

```
let @q = ':echo strftime("%c")'
```

will echo the timestamp in my command line, but how do I get it to insert it into my text?

I found a solution for mapping it to an f-key, but I would prefer a macro. I'm using a Bluetooth keyboard with a mobile device, and I don't have access to all the f-keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have this:

```
ia dt <c-r>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")<cr>
```

In INSERT mode, press `dt<space>` the current TS will be inserted.

If you love macro:

```
let @q="i\<c-r>=strftime('%c')\<cr>\<esc>"
```

then you can `@q`

Comment: `ia` is shorthand for `iabbrev`, just to be a little clearer :-)

Comment: ia dt <c-r>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")<cr> is perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have:

```
iabbrev dts <Esc>"=strftime("%d%b%Y")<CR>pA Rory Hunter -
```

Which in response to typing "dts<Space>" yields e.g.

```
14May2014 Rory Hunter -
```